# Laravel 5.2 - Mail randomly got exception time out

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I'm using PHP 5.6 and Laravel 5.2

My email is running in cron queues. But randomly got the exception timeout.

**Connection to tcp://mail.example.com:587 Timed Out**

Here is my code:

```
    public function sendNotificationByEMail($information){
        Mail::send($information['template'], ['param' => $information['param']], function ($message) use ($information) {
            $message->from('admin@example.com', $information['mailAlias']);
            $message->to($information['mail']);
            if(isset($information['cc']) && !empty($information['cc'])){
                $message->cc($information['cc']);
            }
            $message->subject($information['subject']);
        });
    }
```

```
class SendNotificationEmail extends Job implements ShouldQueue
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;


try {
     $modelHelper->sendNotificationByEMail($result);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
     $param['push_notification_note'] = $ex->getMessage();
}
```

And here is my mail config:

```
 'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mail.example.com'),
 'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
 'from' => ['address' => env('MAIL_FROM'), 'name' => env('MAIL_NAME')],
 'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
 'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
 'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

Is my code is wrong, or is something wrong with the server?

Comment: Do you have access to the mailserver's log file to check whether additional information is recorded there? Are all mails sent even when that error message is given?

Comment: I don't have access to mailserver log file. It's randomly happening and sometimes its throw connection refused too.

Comment: Probably it's a connection issue or smtp server issue. What mail service are you using?